# Quick-Dict or Hash-List : value by key and key by value?

Tags: list, dictionary, lambda, prolog, maplist

Invented quick and dirty Hash-like using a list i.e.

```
 [ key1:val1,key2:val2, ....]
```

I can get the keys and values :

```
hl_keys(HL,Res) :- maplist(\I^K^(I = K:_),HL,Res).
hl_vals(HL,Res) :- maplist(\I^V^(I = _:V),HL,Res).
```

but how do I get specific  value by key and key by value  ?

Comment: Any reason not to use an existing dictionary (aka association list or map) library?

Comment: no, just thought is a clever idea  for small hashes, and can be used for quick args/props ... elixir have something similar

Comment: Assuming a small number of pairs, you could use instead a simple binary tree implementation as its worst case would be the same as a list but in average could provide better performance.

Answer (score 1):

it was easy :

```
hl_val(HL,Key,Res) :- member(Key:Res,HL).
hl_key(HL,Val,Res) :- member(Res:Val,HL).
```

and the good thing is it acts as two-way hash

Comment: It's more idiomatic in Prolog to use `Key-Value` rather than `Key:Value`. Other than that, well done!